# Ошибки при сортировке по времени

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

Мне нужно что бы происходила сортировка по времени но как только добавляю код выводиться ошибка. Без сортировки по времени все отлично. В чем может быть проблема ?

```
 public partial class OthetForm : Form
{
    int Emploer_Id;
    private MySqlCommandBuilder mysqlBuilder = null;
    private MySqlDataAdapter adapter = null;
    private DataSet ds = null;
    string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM othet";
    public MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    static string connectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;database=zzz;password=2Mz-J4w;";
    private bool  newRowAdding = false;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   

    public OthetForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OthetForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     
       

    }

    private void loadData()
    {
        try
        {
           
            string sql = "SELECT *,\"Delete\"  AS \"Delete\"  FROM Othet WHERE time between @d1 and @d2";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mycon);
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", dateTimePicker2.Value);
            mysqlBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            mysqlBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
            mysqlBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            mysqlBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
             ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Othet");
            OthetView.DataSource = ds.Tables["Othet"];
            fillcombo();
            for (int i = 0; i < OthetView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
                OthetView[8, i] = linkCell;
            }
        }
           
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }  
       
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где-то опечатка, в ex.InnerException есть дополнительная информация об ошибке

Comment: возможно не `Othet`, а `Other`

Comment: `ex.Message` замениете для отладки на `ex.ToString()`